# Highlighting overlapping words by character index

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of text, where I want to highlight several words. The words that need to be highlighted are defined by an array of indexes: `[[10, 15], [20, 27], ...]`, these represent the start and end index of the characters that need to be highlighted.

Originally I put this together:

```js
var content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt consequat quam, ut convallis massa euismod at. Proin vel fermentum leo. Suspendisse erat turpis, gravida quis dui sed, mattis consectetur dolor. Curabitur nec tincidunt augue. Donec sapien eros, molestie vel volutpat vitae, vulputate sed ante. Donec finibus consequat dignissim. Donec at nibh eget nibh ultrices gravida. Fusce id molestie eros. Aenean maximus ante et mi elementum, eget pharetra mauris mollis. ";
[[10, 15], [20, 27], [39, 45]].forEach(function(pos) {
        content = content.substring(0, pos[0]) + '<mark>' + content.substring(pos[0], pos[1]) + '</mark>' + content.substring(pos[1]);
})

document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

But this obviously doesn't work very well, since inserting the `<mark>`, changes the indexes in the original text.

How would I go about making this work correctly?

Comment: Maybe you add an offset to the entire Array and adjust it whenever you insert text in front of the text? Just one value that keeps track of where the indexed portion starts

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do it, assuming the mark indices are sorted, would be to just reverse the array, so the remaining indices remain the same in the resulting string

```
[
  [10, 15],
  [20, 27],
  [39, 45],
]
  .reverse()
  .forEach(function (pos) {
    content =
      content.substring(0, pos[0]) +
      '<mark>' +
      content.substring(pos[0], pos[1]) +
      '</mark>' +
      content.substring(pos[1]);
  });
```

If its not sorted, replace the `reverse()` with a custom sort

```
[
  [10, 15],
  [20, 27],
  [39, 45],
]
  .sort(function (a, b) {
    return b[0] - a[0];
  })
  .forEach(function (pos) {
    content =
      content.substring(0, pos[0]) +
      '<mark>' +
      content.substring(pos[0], pos[1]) +
      '</mark>' +
      content.substring(pos[1]);
  });
```

Comment: That's quite a simple and smart solution, and it does work for most instances. However, one of the other problems was overlapping terms.

Comment: You're right, its not perfect, I'm trying to think of a more generic solution for every possibility

Comment: I'm not sure if it's even possible to do it this way, since you can't have overlapping html tags. The other think I thought of, is to get the position of the string of characters that need highlighting, and use absolute positioning.

Comment: You can fix the overlap issue with your original code/idea by going through the array and merging the overlapping markings before the forEach, but its not as easy as it sounds, havent found an efficient way to do it yet

Answer (score 0):

you can use `String#replace`, `13` is the number of characters in `<mark></mark>` we use it in combination withe the index `i` to translate the old indexes to updated one after each insert.

```js
var content = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum tincidunt consequat quam, ut convallis massa euismod at. Proin vel fermentum leo. Suspendisse erat turpis, gravida quis dui sed, mattis consectetur dolor. Curabitur nec tincidunt augue. Donec sapien eros, molestie vel volutpat vitae, vulputate sed ante. Donec finibus consequat dignissim. Donec at nibh eget nibh ultrices gravida. Fusce id molestie eros. Aenean maximus ante et mi elementum, eget pharetra mauris mollis. ";
[[10, 15], [20, 27], [39, 45]].forEach(function(pos,i) {
        content = content.replace(content.substring(pos[0]+13*i, pos[1]+13*i),'<mark>' + content.substring(pos[0]+13*i, pos[1]+13*i) + '</mark>')
})

document.querySelector("#test").innerHTML = content;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```